# Can I keep MYSQL and WAMP Server running together?

Tags: mysql, wamp

At first, I use Struts 2 to develop a website in Java web technology. So I installed Apache Tomcat as the localhost server and MYSQL as the database (MYSQL here is the full application from mysql.com, not the packages like XAMPP or WAMP...)

But now I switch to learn a little bit about PHP so I install WAMP full package. When I start all services of WAMP and go to browser and type localhost, everything work fine

But when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin, it seems to connect to the old MYSQL application in my computer (what I've used in Java web). And then I restart computer and use MYSQL Workbench (in the MYSQL application), but now it connects to the database of WAMP package, and I can not connect to the old database (in Java web) anymore

The solution is remove WAMP but I need WAMP for PHP

So I just want to ask how can I use MYSQL application and WAMP package together (MYSQL application for Java web and WAMP package for PHP)?

Thank you and apology for my bad English!

Answer (score 4):

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1 and open my (Configuration file) and then navigate to

```
[client]

port=3306
```

Change this to

```
[client]

port:3307
```

This will make phpmyadmin to run on 3306 and Java-Mysql to run on 3307

Answer (score 0):

You can of course keep both XAMPP and WAMP running together keeping in mind that you have changed the default ports for either of it to some other ports rather than 80,443 and 3306, but sometimes it could create conflict as when you install some other third party softwares or enable certain services  that run on port 80,443,3306.

The best alternative here would be to install one of the servers  inside a virtual machine with network configured as "host-only-adapter" so that from the base machine you could access XAMPP/WAMP installed on the virtual machine by just pointing the ip-address of the virtual machine through a web-browser.

or,

If you want to run both XAMPP and WAMP together on the same machine but access only one of the servers at a time then you could go ahead installing both of them one after another. But, keep in mind that before installing the other server you have to completely stop all the services running from the XAMPP or WAMP control panel then quit the application. After this step you can go ahead installing the other server without changing any configurations or port numbers. This is because in this case we assumed that only one of the servers would be accessed at a time. Hence, before launching the other server one has to completely quit the application that is running currently by stopping all of it's services. If skype is installed then one has to change the default incoming connection ports to other than port 80 and 443.

Like mentioned above, if at all the intention is to access both servers up and running concurrently then taking advantage of a virtual machine would be the best to avoid conflicts and a long-term troubleshoots eventually.

If you messed up changing ports and config files then you could end up with the following error while trying to access phpmyadmin from XAMPP control panel:

```
    **mysql said: Cannot connect: invalid settings. xampp**
```

**note:** *while launching the servers ,* **run it as administrator** *else some services will not start properly.*

**"I TRIED INSTALLING BOTH XAMPP AND WAMP ON WINDOWS 10 AS SUCH AS POINTED BY MANY THREADS I CHANGED THE DEFAULT PORTS FOR MYSQL & APACHE XAMPP AS IT WOULD CONFLICT WITH WAMP ALREADY INSTALLED ONLY ENDING UP UNABLE TO ACCESS PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. THEN REINSTALLED XAMPP WITHOUT CHANGING ANY CONFIGS OR PORTS. STOP THE WAMP SERVICES, QUIT THE APP AND THEN LAUNCH PHPMYADMIN FROM XAMPP CONTROL PANEL. AT LAST IT WORKED!. THE PROCESS LOOKS SHORT THOUGH WHEN IN REALITY IT TOOK ME COUNTLESS HOURS AND PAIN RESEARCHING ON THE WEB AND TESTING FOR A POSSIBLE SOLUTION UNTILL I CAME UP WITH THIS."**

Hopes, this quick tips and guides would be helpful.